# Tooltip on image hover not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently having an issue, you can check it [here](https://www.tudecoradorasofas.com/). If you hover the mouse over the logo you will see a tooltip. Thats OK, but

If you try it with Firefox the tooltip is stuck under the logo (correct)

If you try it with Chrome the tooltip follows the mouse (incorrect)

How can I fix this?

Im using the following code, which I found on on this site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showTooltip(e, tooltip)
{
    e = window.event ? window.event : e;
    tooltip = document.getElementById(tooltip);
    if(tooltip.style.display != "block")
        tooltip.style.display = "block";
    tooltip.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
    tooltip.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
}

function hideTooltip(e, tooltip)
{
    e = window.event ? window.event : e;
    tooltip = document.getElementById(tooltip);
    if(e.toElement == tooltip)
    {
        showTooltip(e, tooltip);
        return;
    }
    tooltip.style.display = "none";
}
```

And this is the logo code

```
<img class="logo-main scale-with-grid hastooltip" 
src="#" onmousemove="showTooltip(event, 'dvTooltip');" 
onmouseout="hideTooltip(event, 'dvTooltip');" /> 

<div id="dvTooltip" style="display:none;position:absolute;background-color:#191919; padding: 15px; bottom: -87px; z-index: 100;" 
onmousemove="showTooltip(event, 'dvTooltip');">

CONTENT
</div>
```

I need the box to stick under the logo and not follow the mouse on Chrome, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Chrome is working correctly :), your code is instructing the tooltip to move.

Any way here is a working version of your code

```
var logo = document.querySelector('.hastooltip');
var tooltip = document.querySelector('#dvTooltip');

// Set tooltip height
tooltip.style.height = '60px';

function showTooltip(e) {
  e = window.event ? window.event : e; 

  if(tooltip.style.display != "block"){
      tooltip.style.display = "block";
      tooltip.style.position = "fixed";
  }

  tooltip.style.left = (logo.getBoundingClientRect().x - 30) + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = (logo.getBoundingClientRect().y + logo.getBoundingClientRect().height + 10) + 'px';
}
```

This part "tooltip.style.height = '60px';" you can ommit, if you add the height to the DOM element.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer.

I just swapped my JS code for your JS code but the tooltip is not showing. 

I tried to figure a small error on the code but I couldnt, my JS skills are very low.

Again, thanks you so much